# RequireJs : Module not defined

Tags: javascript, requirejs, commonjs

I am trying to use require in my simple javascript file, with file defined in module.exports, but unfortunately i am getting error  **Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined**, did I miss any thing.

*a.js*

```
  function Dosomthing() {
    console.log('234234');
}

module.exports = Dosomthing;
```

main.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.15/require.js"></script>
    <script>
    var doSomething = require(['a']);
       doSomething();
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

link : http://plnkr.co/edit/Lk3KDNcBAx5z6Wz2KF7v?p=preview

Comment: It depends on your configuration. Do you have proper requirejs configuration file? A good start would be [RequireJS How to get started](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) documentation.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to actually use [browserify](http://browserify.org/)?

Comment: @kryger : Yes, no idea how to use it, can you help me on this